# unable to browse VirtualBox guest from a windows 7 host using samba

Tags: windows-7, centos, virtualbox, samba, shared-directory

I have a CentOS linux running in VirtualBox as a guest under Win7 host.
What I wanna do is to share folders in CentOS and make them visible in Win7

I did the following:

installed samba, it is working well, services are running, using the following smb.conf:

```
#============== [ Global Settings ] ===============
[global]    
netbios name = CentOS    
workgroup = WORKGROUP    
server string = CentOS    
security = share    
wins support = yes    
map to guest = bad user    
\#============== [ Share Definitions ] ===============
[MyShare]
path = /home/dev/share    
browsable = yes    
writable = yes    
guest ok = no    
read only = no    
valid users = dev
```

In Win7 host typing **net view** in a command prompt sometimes shows nothing, sometimes lists the following:

```
\\CENTOS         CentOS
\\DESKTOP-3
\\LOCALHOST      CentOS
```

which looks almost fine, but opening \\LOCALHOST does not open the guest's shared folders but the host's, like it was DESKTOP-3.

I cannot open \\CENTOS, neither can see in Networks window.

I am using bridged network card, switched off windows firewall.

What should I do to see and browse guest OS' shared folders?

Comment: \\192.168.xxx.xxx isn't working, ping is ok

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox has a feature called Shared Folders that allows sharing  folders between guest and host. Please check the VirtualBox manual here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders for information on how to install and use it.

Hint: You will need to install VirtualBox Guest Additions inside your guest. It is always recommended to use the official VirtualBox Guest Additions rather than the ones supplied by the Linux distros.

The guest additions should be available already if you have VirtualBox installed. Choose "Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD image" after booting your guest.

Once it's done, it's very easy to share this way.